# Application getting force stop

Tags: android, json, exception, nullpointerexception

I have an activity in which i am trying to make a web service call for a url and display the json response into the activity, but my app is getting force stop as soon as i go on that activity.

My RedemptionActivity is like this:

```
  public class RedemptionActivity extends Activity {

ListView redemptionListView;
RedemptionListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.redemption);
    redemptionListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.redemptionListView);

    if (SnapDineCommon.getInstance(this).isNetworkAvailable()) {

            new RedemptionResultAsyncTask(this).execute();

    } else
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.check_network),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}



public class RedemptionResultAsyncTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    Context context;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    RedemptionResultResponse redemptionResultResponse;

    public RedemptionResultAsyncTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            RestWebServiceClient client = new RestWebServiceClient(
                    SnapDineCommon.getInstance(this.context).SiteUrl
                            + "getRedemptionData", this.context);
            client.AddParam("mobile_number",
                    SnapDineCommon.getInstance(context)
                            .getLoggedinMobileNumber());
            client.Execute(RequestMethod.GET);
            String response = client.getResponse();
            if (response == null)
                return false;
            else {
                redemptionResultResponse = gson.fromJson(response,
                        RedemptionResultResponse.class);
                if (redemptionResultResponse == null)
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        progressDialog = null;
        if (result) {
            if (redemptionResultResponse.Success) {
                if (redemptionResultResponse.getSearchResult().size() > 0) {         //throwing null pointer exception
                    adapter = new RedemptionListAdapter(context,
                            R.layout.searchresult_row,
                            redemptionResultResponse.getSearchResult());
                    redemptionListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                } else {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context,
                            GenericOkDialogActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, redemptionResultResponse.errorMessage,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "An error occured. Please try later.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}


}
```

and logcat show following errors:

```
 04-10 14:04:21.545: E/AndroidRuntime(6798): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 04-10 14:04:21.545: E/AndroidRuntime(6798): java.lang.NullPointerException
 04-10 14:04:21.545: E/AndroidRuntime(6798):    at com.JustDine.GUI.RedemptionActivity$RedemptionResultAsyncTask.onPostExecute(RedemptionActivity.java:101)
 04-10 14:04:21.545: E/AndroidRuntime(6798):    at com.JustDine.GUI.RedemptionActivity$RedemptionResultAsyncTask.onPostExecute(RedemptionActivity.java:1)
 04-10 14:04:21.545: E/AndroidRuntime(6798):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
 04-10 14:04:21.545: E/AndroidRuntime(6798):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
 04-10 14:04:21.545: E/AndroidRuntime(6798):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
 04-10 14:04:21.545: E/AndroidRuntime(6798):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 04-10 14:04:21.545: E/AndroidRuntime(6798):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 04-10 14:04:21.545: E/AndroidRuntime(6798):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 04-10 14:04:21.545: E/AndroidRuntime(6798):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 04-10 14:04:21.545: E/AndroidRuntime(6798):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 04-10 14:04:21.545: E/AndroidRuntime(6798):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
 04-10 14:04:21.545: E/AndroidRuntime(6798):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
 04-10 14:04:21.545: E/AndroidRuntime(6798):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 04-10 14:04:21.555: W/ActivityManager(124):   Force finishing activity com.JustDine.GUI/.RedemptionActivity
 04-10 14:04:21.555: W/AppErrorDialog(124): xjzb001 AppErrorDialog setLongMsg=java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I am unable to figure out why it is closing unexpectedly. Please help, why `"redemptionResultResponse.getSearchResult().size()"` is null, i have confirmed that redemptionResultResponse is not null..?????

**Updated: here is what i have in RedemptionResultResponse:**

```
  @SerializedName("Success")
public boolean Success;

@SerializedName("GetSearchResult")
private List<SearchResult> getSearchResult;

@SerializedName("errorMessage")
public String errorMessage;

@SerializedName("Tag")
public String Tag;

public List<SearchResult> getSearchResult() {
    return getSearchResult;
}

public void setSearchResult(List<SearchResult> getSearchResult) {
    this.getSearchResult = getSearchResult;
}
```

**Updated XML**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LoginScreen"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#f0f0f0"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/realtiveLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibSearchResultsBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/backbtn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Search Result"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/settingLayout"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/settingicon" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/light_red_gradient" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search.."
    android:singleLine="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="8" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/redemptionListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/light_red_gradient" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What line of code is at `RedemptionActivity.java:101`? Something there is `null` and you're trying to use it

Comment: you get nullpointerexception meaning something is null. check line RedemptionActivity.java:101

Comment: @MattTaylor: if (redemptionResultResponse.getSearchResult().size() > 0) { is at 101..

Comment: Then `getSearchResult()` returns something that's null.

Comment: Then either `redemptionResultResponse` is null, or `redemptionResultResponse.getSearchResult()` is returning null

Comment: i already have a condition if redemptionResultResponse then it will return false..

Comment: or redemptionListView is null

Comment: I think you haven't initialized the listview. That may be problem.

Comment: @Selvin: Yes my listview is empty, and when i am declaring it, it show an error `"redemptionListView cannot be resolved or is not a field"`..

Comment: click on the line just below    -10 14:04:21.545: E/AndroidRuntime(6798): java.lang.NullPointerException   it will take you to the place where there is null pointer error, mark the line here!

Comment: I have already mentioned the line in above comments..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured the error. The error was json in response class, where i didn't correctly parsed the json data, which was throwing the exception.

Refer [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html).

Thanks all for your response.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `dismiss()` on the `progressDialog`, you are basically removing it from memory using the `GC`, you don't need to call `progressDialog = null;`

if  `if (redemptionResultResponse.getSearchResult().size() > 0)` is crashing due to `NullPointerException` then my guess would be that `getSearchResult()` returns `NULL`.

Comment: If redemptionResultresponse is not null then how come getSearchResult returns null, i have updated the declaration of it just now..??

Comment: I have removed `progressDialog = null;` the errors are still the same.

Comment: are you sure that getSearchResult List is not null, I don't see in your code that you ever setting it using the setSearchResult method.

Comment: i think its not null, instead  my listview is empty, and when i am declaring it, it show an error "redemptionListView cannot be resolved or is not a field"..how do i declare it?

Comment: i have declared it aa `redemptionListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.redemptionListView);` throws above error..

Answer (score 0):

Show us your XML file ...This kind of Error will occur due to your Xml file is containing some Error..The null pointer Exception Shows that URL which you requesting is not returning any thing ..Refer [here](http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/05/android-programming-tutorial-a-simple-twitter-feed-reader/)..

Comment: Updated XMl, but it isnt have to do anything with XML i think.